# Binding List of strings to a DataGridView gives strings properties

Tags: c#, datagridview

I found one similar question in StackOverflow, but it has no answers. I'm trying to bind a `IList<string>` to a `DataGridView` as its `DataSource`, but instead of it output the list of strings, like in a `ListView`, it outputs me the properties of the elements in the list, in this case, `Length`.

My code:

```
public void FindMatches()
{
    const string regex = @"\{([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)\}";
    IList<string> names = (from Match match in Regex.Matches(ObterConteudoArquivo(), regex) select match.Value).ToList();
    _view.Lista = names;
}
```

Now that I have a list stored in `List` that contains all my matches, example given `{ "{CP}", "{DP}", "{EP"} }`, I want to bind them to my `DataGridView:`

```
public IList<string> Lista
{
    set
    {
        ltvCampos.DataSource = value;
    }
}
```

This binds only the `Length` of each string.
I also did:

```
public IList<string> Lista
{
    set
    {
        foreach (string name in value)
        {
            DataGridTextBox row = new DataGridTextBox();
            row.Text = name;
            ltvCampos.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
}
```

The lexer says:

```
Method with 'params' is invoked. Have you intended to call more specific method 'int Add(object)'?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **wrap** your strings in a class, which exposes them as public properties with both a setter and a getter:

```
class aString { public string theString { get; set; } 
                public aString(string s) { theString = s; }  }
```

Now create a list of strings..

```
List<aString> theStrings = new List<aString>();
```

..and fill it with your Matches:

```
theStrings  = (from Match match in Regex.Matches(text, regex) 
               select new aString(match.Value)).ToList();
```

Now you can bind your list to the DGV:

```
ltvCampos.DataSource = theStrings;
```

For added functionality you may want to insert one or two more layers of binding by using a `BindingList` (which among others will raise change events):

```
var blist = new BindingList<aString>(theStrings);
ltvCampos.DataSource = theStrings;
```

or both a `BindingList` and a `BindingSource`, which will present you with a wider range of options and methods:

```
var blist = new BindingList<aString>(theStrings);
var source = new BindingSource(blist, null);
ltvCampos.DataSource = source ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer on [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/17460a5f-1222-4582-8ef0-853aecaed1b7/binding-liststring-to-datagridview).  I think it is going to help you.  They are using a **BindingList<>** instead of an **IList<>**