# Issue displaying dictionary list values in listbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, dictionary, listbox

I currently have two list boxes. One is to store the key and the second is to view the list associated with it.

The following code I have displays the key in the first listBox but fails to show the list in the second:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(textBox1.Text);


        var node = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("pdml/packet/proto[@name='ip']/@showname");

        foreach (XmlAttribute attribute1 in node)
        {
            string ip = attribute1.Value;
            var arr = ip.Split(); var src = arr[5]; var dst = arr[8];

            Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            List<string> listDST;

            if (!dict.TryGetValue(src, out listDST))
            {
                dict[src] = l = new List<string>();
            }

            l.Add(listDST);

            listBoxSRC.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict,null);
            listBoxSRC.DisplayMember = "Value";
            listBoxSRC.ValueMember = "Key";

        }
    }

    private void listBoxSRC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBoxSRC.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var keyValue = (KeyValuePair<string, List<String>>)listBoxSRC.SelectedItem;
            listBoxDST.DataSource = keyValue.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            listBoxDST.DataSource = null;
        }
    }
```

I have checked using the debugger to make sure that there is data contained in the dictionaries list so I am not sure what the problem is.

Can anyone point out where I maybe going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Just try using your own class to hold data, ListView show what you allow it in ToString()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lists of 'naked' strings can't be used as a `DataSource`. You need to wrap them in a simple class with a real property. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25080903/binding-list-of-strings-to-a-datagridview-gives-strings-properties/25093244#25093244)

After you have declared a simple string wrapper class:

```
class aString { public string theString { get; set; } 
                public aString(string s) { theString = s; }  
                public override string ToString() {return theString;} }
```

you can either change your Dictionary to contain a `List<aString>` or you can create a `List<aString>` from your `Dictionary Values`:

```
List<aString> aStringList = dict [src].Select(item => new aString(item) ).ToList();
listBoxDST.DataSource = aStringList ;
```

The ListBox can now display the `aString.ToString()` values.

Answer (score 0):

try this man

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.Load(textBox1.Text);


    var node = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("pdml/packet/proto[@name='ip']/@showname");

    foreach (XmlAttribute attribute1 in node)
    {
        string ip = attribute1.Value;
        var arr = ip.Split(); var src = arr[5]; var dst = arr[8];

        Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string,List<string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        List<string> listDST;

        if (!dict.TryGetValue(src, out listDST))
        {
            dict[src] = l = new List<string>();
        }

        l.Add(listDST);

    }
    listBoxSRC.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict,null);
    listBoxSRC.DisplayMember = "Value";
    listBoxSRC.ValueMember = "Key";
}

private void listBoxSRC_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBoxSRC.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        var keyValue = (KeyValuePair<string, List<String>>)listBoxSRC.SelectedItem;
        listBoxDST.DataSource = keyValue.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        listBoxDST.DataSource = null;
    }
}
```